# Are there any mandatory attributes for Products attribute sets?

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute, attribute-set

When building a new Attribute set for Products in the backend. Are there any mandatory attributes that should be included in the custom attribute set?

Comment: Yes there are. But I have no list :(

Comment: According to http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product_attribute/index . "all Attribute Sets must include these attributes (more on Attribute sets in the next section). These type of attributes include Name, Price, and SKU, without which a product would not function."
But the problem is even with that attributes i couldn't make my configurable product work :( .

Comment: There are two configurable (dropdown) attributes in my attribute set + Name, Price and SKU.

Comment: While creating attribute sets, you need to select the previous attribute sets on which you are creating your new attribute set. Or by default you can select the "default" set for your new attribute set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that all the attributes marked as `system` (or `is_user_defined` = 0) since you cannot remove them from the `Default` attribute set.
Here is a list of the attribute codes that fall in this category. There are quite a few.

```
name
description
short_description
sku
price
special_price
special_from_date
special_to_date
weight
meta_title
meta_keyword
meta_description
image
small_image
thumbnail
media_gallery
group_price
tier_price
news_from_date
news_to_date
gallery
status
url_key
url_path
minimal_price
is_recurring
recurring_profile
visibility
custom_design
custom_design_from
custom_design_to
custom_layout_update
page_layout
category_ids
options_container
required_options
has_options
image_label
small_image_label
thumbnail_label
created_at
updated_at
country_of_manufacture
msrp_enabled
msrp_display_actual_price_type
msrp
enable_googlecheckout
tax_class_id
gift_message_available
price_type
sku_type
weight_type
price_view
shipment_type
links_purchased_separately
samples_title
links_title
links_exist
```

You can get the list of these attributes from this query

```
SELECT 
    e.attribute_code 
FROM 
    eav_attribute e 
WHERE 
    e.entity_type_id = 
      (SELECT 
          entity_type_id 
       FROM 
          eav_entity_type 
       WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
      )  
     AND e.is_user_defined = 0
```